# Have to sort Divs grid by clicking on header div(not used table)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used just `div` tags (boot) to construct a grid. There are four `div` elements for headers. I loop through them to retrieve data. Now I have to sort this grid by clicking on the header `div`. Can any one help me please? I have to use `div` elements only for responsiveness, and I am not allowed to use plug-ins.

I have tried to sort the `div` by using the `sort()` method.

But after sorting, I need to append the entire row rather than that particular column. There I am facing a problem.

```
var alpha = $("#rowscontent .sortname a").get().sort(div each(function (index, value) {       
    var alphaArr = [];
    alphaArr.push(value.text);
    alphaArr.push($(this));
    alpha.push(alphaArr);
    alpha.sort();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding: 10px;margin-bottom:20px">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="display:inline-block"><b>Name</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:-20px"><b>File Type</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="display:inline-block"><b>Expiration Date</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="display:inline-block"><b>Last Modified</b></div>
        </div>
@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3  @item.DocumentID sortname" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline-block; word-break:break-all;padding-left:55px"><a href="@item.DocumentUrl ">@item.DocumentName</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1  @item.DocumentID" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline-block"> <img src="@item.FileType" alt="Image" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2  @item.DocumentID" style="cursor:pointer;padding-left:0px; display:inline-block">@item.DocumentCreated.AddYears(5).ToShortDateString()</div>
}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without your html it's very hard to tell you why it's not working.

Comment: Please add your HTML code.

Comment: Add HTML code so that any one can help you, if you are unable to add HTML code then give screen shot of how it is displaying currently.

Comment: Well, we can tell why it is not working: `alpha.sort()` will not affect the page, nor does it reliable to sort `alpha` by text. But we need to see the context to provide you with a working alternative.

Comment: I have added my html divs in the post.I cant share my screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Your HTML does not have any element with id `rowscontent` so `$("#rowscontent .sortname a")` will not select anything.
- Both header and data rows are within one single `<div class="row">`, which seems wrong. You should have each row in a separate container `div`.
- `alpha.sort()` will convert the elements (which are arrays) to string and compare those while sorting. This might not always return the desired result. But even then, sorting `alpha` has no effect on the HTML content.

Here is how it would work:

```
$(".container .row").slice(1).get().sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(".sortname a", a).text().localeCompare($(".sortname a", b).text());
}).forEach(function (rowDiv) {
    $(".container").append(rowDiv);
});
```

This will select the rows (not the `a` elements), and then sort those with a callback function. That callback will then grab the texts in the `a` elements of two rows and compare those.

The resulting array of sorted row `div` elements is then re-appending in their sorted order to the container `div`, which actually moves them in the right order.